# Polyline disappearing intermittently in layout view

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, arcgis-10.4

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.4.1 and I'm running into an issue with a polyline disappearing. This exhibit has 4 data frames on it each with a combination of polygons and polylines.  The data frame where the issue occurs is 5.5 inch by 7 inch, with a scale of 1 inch = 820 feet.  This specific layer is symbolized into 2 fields, I'll call them 1 and 2 for simplicity.  Line 1 line type is HiddenX2, line 2 is Hidden, both width of 1.0.  They are straight lines, only 2 vertices for each.

The issue occurs when I switch from data view to layout view.  In data view, both lines show up exactly how I want.  When I switch to layout view, line 1 shows up fine, however, line 2 messes up with parts of the line disappearing. For example, one of the lines, about half is missing while another line is missing the first and last third.  Then there will be some that show up entirely.  One thing I noticed is when I switch the line type to continuous, it shows up.  Or if I keep the line type at Hidden but change the scale to 1 inch = 1000 feet, it'll show up as well.

Has anyone seen this?

Is there a fix for it?

Is it a graphics deal with the line type/scale?

What I ended up doing to cover it up is create a line in layout view to fake it.

Data View on Top, Layout View on Bottom
[image: Data View on Top, Layout View on Bottom]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: Done.  Probably should of turned off the polygons, but it's the yellow line type near the center.

Comment: Does actual document render drop the line too?  ArcMap has the one of the worse renders in my experience, I have to restart it at least once a day for weird stuff like this.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about document render, can you elaborate on that please?  Are you referring to the refresh (F5) button?  I know restarting the computer and/or software does nothing.

Comment: I am assume since you are using the layout view, you are exporting an image or document to use elsewhere.  Is the actual export of the document missing the line, or is it just showing it in the layout view on-screen.

Comment: Roma, it is missing in both print and in layout view on-screen.  I still haven't figured this one out and coming to the conclusion that its a glitch in the software.